# AngularJS Directive What means Replace and Transclude?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can somebody explains what means:

```
replace: true / false
```

and

```
transclude: true / false
```

in an angularjs directive?

I did read the documentation but could understand it 100%.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

Whenever you say `replace: true`, you are telling your directive to replace your directive tag with the template of directive.

Assume you have used `template: '<div>This is directive template</div>'` in your directive that look like `<div data-my-directive></div>` When you run your application all the directives div in DOM will be replaced by `<div>This is directive template</div>`

However in the same scenario if you declare `replace: false` Your DOM will have something like this

```
<div data-my-directive>
    <div>This is directive template</div>
</div>
```

TRANSCLUDE

You use `ng-transclude`, you want to append data in the directive template from controller of your view.

Lets say you have template in your directive which looks like

```
template: '<div class="main"><div data-ng-transclude></div></div>'
```

So when you set `transclude: true` you are explicitly telling your directive to allow all the transcluded values to be part of directive itself when DOM loads.

Lets say you have used the directive in your view like this:

```
<div data-my-directive>
    Transcluded data
</div>
```

You will see th the text `Transcluded data` in your web page, however if you have set `transclude: false` You wont see the text `Transcluded data`

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple:

#### Replace `true` will replace your directive's template with the tag from where you called your directive:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

if replace is true will become:

```
<div>bla bla</div>
```

if replace is false will become:

```
<my-directive><div>bla bla</div></my-directive>
```

#### Transclude will "copy" whatever is inside your directive, and append it somewhere on your template:

```
<my-directive>This is some content</my-directive>
```

if transclude is true:

```
<my-directive>
   <div>bla bla</div>
   <span>This is some content</span> <!--for this to work your template needs to use the ng-transclude directive -->
</my-directive>
```

if transclude is false:

```
<my-directive>
    <div>bla bla</div>
</my-directive>
```

Comment: Your transclude true/false code blocks are exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoLackovic I've fixed it